# Can I measures the internet speed purely over http?

Tags: networking, browser, network-programming

I wanna make a test program which tests internet speed.

I tried to do that by using WebSocket via TCP Protocol, But the WebSockets are also not purely TCP,

Because to connect with server via tcp from browser using WebSocket, first of all, WebSocket try to connect http first. then, HTTP will accept to connect as TCP connection to server.

so that, if I make a program which uses websocket. It is meaningless.

Is it possible to measure the internet speed via http?

I would be pleased by receiving great answer.

Have a nice day, Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it matters which protocol you use as long as the program adds up all the bytes of the packets rather than just the data portion of the packet. Quite simply, download speed = Number of bits downloaded / time taken. It matters little what was downloaded and what protocol headers were used to download it.

Comment: @wookie919 Thanks for your answer. but I want to measure upload speed as well, is it also same with that?

Comment: Yes, the principle is exactly the same. Upload speed = Number of bits uploaded / time taken.